# ASP.NET if array has string

Tags: asp.net, arrays

I have an array with 3 items "AAA", "BBB" & "CCC"

I have a string and its value is "CCC"

I am looking for a condition that will take this string and check if its in the array.

I get the array via:

```
string[] departmentArray = newDepartment.Split(',');
```

and the string

```
string department = "CCC";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[String.Contains](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) could well work here.

```
if (newDepartment.Contains(department)) {
// the substring is in the big one.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `if (departmentArray.Contains(department)) ...`